# Filtering a file path against several strings with awk

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I'm trying to filter a file path in a script with awk so it omits anything within a regular expression:

```
FILTERED_FILE=$(echo $File |  awk -F / "{(for(i=NF; i>=0; i--) {if $(i!~^(NewConfig|Old|old|backup|Backup|Servers)$ print $i}}") ;
```

What I'm basically trying to do iterate field by field and extract the first field in the filepath that does not contain any of these keywords.
So, if the file path is, for example:

```
/etc/Backup/Servers/blah/Old
```

I want the variable `$FILTERED_FILE` to be `blah`.

This *exact* line worked as expected in a different script, but now, the awk variable ($i) remains empty.
I'm very much a beginner with awk, so I'm certain to be missing something - I'd be grateful for advice on where to look.
I don't think this line is dependent on any other line in the script (again, this worked in a previous script from which I adapted this one), but I'll upload more if necessary.
I'm not commited to awk either - if you can think of a better tool (grep, sed, etc) it's just as good.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are several issues with your shell as well as your `awk` code.

First, always place the `awk` code in single quotes, as in `awk '<commands>'`. Otherwiese, strange effects may happen such as the *shell* interpreting `$<...>` statements.

Second, your syntax looks wrong at several places:

- You say are looking for the *first* field that doesn't match, but seem to be looking for the *last* one? However, your code would print *all* other non-matching fields, too, since you don't break out of the loop after the first match was found.
- The RegExp comparison should look like

  ```
  if ($i !~ /^( .... )$/) { ... }
  ```
- In your example code, the closing bracket of the `if` statement is missing.

Third, you should also double-quote command substitutions in your shell scripts.

The revised  `awk` code would be

```
awk -F '/' '{for (i=NF; i>0; i--) {if ($i !~ /^(NewConfig|[Oo]ld|[Bb]ackup|Servers)$/) {print $i; exit}}}'
```

And to call it from within a script, use

```bsh
Filtered_File="$( echo "$File" | awk -F '/' ' .... ')"
```

Note that this last part will really only work inside a script because of the `!~` construct. When done on the command-line, at least `bash` will try to perform command history expansion before starting the sub-shell used for the command-substitution, which leads to an error message.

Comment: Hi, previous comment was mistaken. Everything is working beautifully. Thank you!